# Why is the green LED not lighting up?

Tags: led, resistors, breadboard

I suppose the green and red are connected in parallel state.

1. Why is the green one not lighting up?
2. Why is it not green-1, red-0?

[image]
3. I am using a 9V battery. How are the bulbs even lighting up? Shouldn’t they require a resistor?

Comment: A red LED requires less voltage difference across it than green ones. The red one cramps things enough to keep the green one off. That's so anyway with a resistor used to limit current. I think you are saying you aren't using one?

Comment: 3. Yes, a fully charged 9V battery without a current limiting resistor should burn up an LED very quickly. Perhaps the 9V battery is essentially dead.

Comment: @periblepsis Can you please elaborate “cramp things up”, I am very interested about this problem.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy thanks for clearing the 3rd point

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy but how do I check if it’s dead, i tested using multimeter it’s showing “6.9V”?

Comment: 6.9V at no load is nearly dead for a 9V alkaline battery. You can use it as long as it provides enough voltage for your specific application, but for most application this is dead or nearly dead. And expect the voltage to start decreasing very fast quite soon

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. Image (mine) source: [LEDnique.com](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/).*

LEDs' colour depends on the doping material used in manufacture. Each type has a slightly different voltage and this increases as we move from infrared to ultra-violet.

You've got a red in parallel with a green and we can see from the graph that if the red turns on it will pull the voltage down to less than that required to turn on the green.

Connecting the LEDs without a resistor was risky. Your battery must be quite weak if the LEDs have survived the abuse.

Comment: "Y" curve should be to the left of "G" curve.  "W" curve and "B" curve should be one and the same. I don't trust that diagram.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, I created that diagram for my LEDnique website and I found it quite difficult to get any half-decent curves or datapoints from the datasheets. The problem was exacerbated by not being able to find anyone making a complete range of LEDs in the same product range. (i.e., similar packaging, power and efficiency). I did start a project for an Arduino-based LED curve tracer. Maybe I'll get it out again and finish it off. I still have the problem of getting a range of LEDs that are comparable though.

Comment: @Transistor I used to use a doorbell transformer ([leakage transformer](http://electroncoil.com/leakage_transformers.php)) coupled with a 10 kOhm (or 1 kOhm) resistor to create a crappy current source into an LED or diode using an added 10 Ohm resistor to ground and place the scope in X-Y with probes attached across the diode. I got the breakdown part of the curve, though. And that may not be good, but at times may still be desired. I'm thinking now about providing two features: (1) arbitrary bipolar current limit; and (2) arbitrary bipolar sweep voltage limit. Only one of the two active.

Answer (score 2):

The forward voltage of an LED depends on the LED colour - red LEDs are about 1.8 volts while green LEDs are 2.2 volts or more.

The red LED will hold the voltage across the parallel LEDs to about 1.8 volts which is not high enough to light the green LED.

Apparently your 9 volt battery is well used.  With no current limiting resistor, a fresh 9 volt battery should destroy the LEDs fairly quickly.  A used battery will have a high internal resistance which will limit the current the LEDs can draw.

If you a a resistor of 1000 Ohms or so in series with each LED, and connect the two LED/resistor pairs in parallel both LEDs should light.